# How to make resizable with handle dynamically? without ui

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function for drag and drop resizing and I have a problem. The script doesn't react to mouse cursor direction changes instantly. If I hold the button down and move cursor right, then left, it will only keep on increasing object's size for a moment.
[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/U9vre/)

Javascript:

```
var re_dragging = false, re_om_x, re_om_y, re_o_x, re_o_y, re_n_x, re_n_y;
function resize(resize_btn){
    resize_btn.mousedown(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        re_dragging = true;
        re_om_x = e.pageX;
        re_om_y = e.pageY;// origin mouse postion
        target_wp = $(e.target).closest('.draggable_wp').find('.draggable_el');
    });
    $(document).mousemove(function(e){
        if(re_dragging){
            target_wp.width((e.pageX - re_om_x) + target_wp.width());
        }
    });
    $(document).mouseup(function(e){
        re_dragging = false;
    });
};
var resize_btn = $('.draggable_btn_resize');
resize(resize_btn);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="draggable_wp">
    <div class="wp_img">
        <img src=""class="draggable_el">
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <div class="draggable_btn_resize"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need update `re_om_x` after reseting width using `re_om_x = e.pageX;`.

And I add a new variable `width`, because in `target_wp.width((e.pageX - re_om_x) + target_wp.width());`, the `target_wp.width()` will bring in deviation, it is always get a int.

I rewrite `mousemove` as below:

```
 $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
     if (re_dragging) {
         target_wp.width((e.pageX - re_om_x) + width);
         width = (e.pageX - re_om_x) + width
         re_om_x = e.pageX;

     }
 });
```

Here is demo. http://jsfiddle.net/U9vre/1/

Answer (score -1):

For simplicity, see the jQuery UI function [.resizable()](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/). Just remember that you would then need to add the jqueryui .css and .js scripts to your page. You would then just need to call

```
$("#some_div_to_resize").resizable();
```